# Como manipular bit a bit um inteiro em c ou ccs?

Tags: c, pic

Quero mudar um `bit` uma variável inteira em `C`/`CSS` para `pic`.

Ex: mudar algum bit para virar outro número.

> 15 = 0b00001111 -> 0b00001101 = 13.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Solução geral em C

Regra geral, para "apagar" um bit, é isso:

```
valor &= ~( 1 << bitPos);
```

e para "acender", é isso:

```
valor |= 1 << bitPos;
```

sendo que `bitPos` é a posição do bit, sendo zero o mais à direita.

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/T8BSjF)**.

Se quiser manipular mais de um *bit* por vez, pode fazer assim também:

```
int valor   = 15 // 0b00001111;

int mascara = 70 // 0b01000101;
               //BIT: 76543210

resultado1 = valor |  mascara;  // 0b01001111 ("acendi"  os bits 0,2 e 6)
resultado2 = valor & ~mascara;  // 0b00001010 ("apaguei" os bits 0,2 e 6)
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/W70Mc1)**

### Exemplo:

```
int valor = 15 // 0b00001111;
valor &= ~( 1 << 0 );     // valor = 14 ( 0b00001110 ) - "apagamos"  o bit 0
valor |= 1 << 5;          // valor = 46 ( 0b00101110 ) - "acendemos" o bit 5
valor &= ~( 1 << 1 );     // valor = 44 ( 0b00101100 ) - "apagamos"  o bit 1
valor |= 1 << 0;          // valor = 45 ( 0b00101101 ) - "acendemos" o bit 0
```

### Funções do CCS

De acordo com o colega Bruno, há as funções `bit_set(número, bit)` e `bit_clear(número, bit)`, vide resposta correspondente.

### De curiosidade, se fosse para Arduino:

Só pra complementar, se alguém se interessar em equivalente para o Arduino, temos funções similares às do CCS:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage

Temos estas duas funções:

- [`bitSet(x, n)`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/BitSet)
- [`bitClear(x, n)`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/BitClear)

Sendo que `x` é o valor a ser alterado, e `n` o bit a ser alterado, sendo `0` o bit mais à direita.

Comment: O prefixo 0b para números binários não é padrão do C, é uma extensão do gcc (e provavelmente de outros compiladores, mas até onde sei o compilador C da Microsoft, por exemplo, não tem essa extensão).

Comment: @JoseX eu poderia ter mencionado que é C++14 (aliás, acho ridiculo terem demorado tanto), se bem que no contexto da pergunta eu pus para visualização (e o autor usou no código original, que era o alvo da resposta). De qq forma, passei para comments para não confundir, caso alguém resolva copiar e compilar como está em algum contexto diferente do autor.

Comment: C++14...não existe C14...

Comment: Minha experiência é que normalmente se utiliza hexadecimal para trabalhar com bits, tanto no C quanto no C++. Acho que é até mais prático do que usar o prefixo 0b.

Comment: @JoséX. Ou mais prático, ou talvez consequência do hábito de usar sem por falta de opção no começo. Pra coisas como enums, realmente é facil ver 1,2,4,8,10,20,40,80 mas para um mapa de caracteres ou máscaras de bit, por exemplo, base 2 dá visualização instantânea. Agora, é claro que cada um deve usar o que for mais confortável, desde que no padrão do time.

Answer (score 4):

O CCS tem as funções `bit_set(número, bit)`, que seta o bit como `1` e `bit_clear(número, bit)` que reseta o bit como `0`!